# Full-stack development with Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Anyone has experience creating both back-end and front-end using Dart (and UI with Flutter)? Flutter + Firebase doesn't count.

Looking into server-side alternatives to ASP.NET MVC (C#) or Flask (Pyhton), but specifically tailored to Dart.

Would be interested to see examples of tech stacks used and comparisons of past experience with conventional frameworks (.NET, Java, PHP) to Flutter/Dart stack.

Answer (score 1):

#### List of HTTP server frameworks for Dart

1. [Angel](https://pub.dev/packages/angel_framework) - [Website](https://angel-dart.dev/)
2. [Aqueduct](https://pub.dev/packages/aqueduct)
3. [Shelf](https://pub.dev/packages/shelf)